# Construct object, where one of its properties depends on another. In C++

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, constructor

- Beginner in C++

I have a class, say

```
class A
{
  public:

  int N;
  double ..... 
};
```

But I would like the ..... to define a matrix of size depending on N. In case that changes the approach, it is a non-identical function of N and not just N itself, say N^3+1.

- In case that is the approach, I have never written a constructor of an object in C++. Therefore, if this is the approach could you please give some detail. I don't understand how it might work. When the class is instanciated, maybe the property N hasn't been even initialized.
- I am not clear how to get a matrix or array (I am still not clear of the basic data types of C++) of size determined in execution.

**Edit:** The value of N is determined later in the code. It is something like:

```
A InstanceOfA; //The variable InstanceOfA is declared of type A.
...
Some other stuff happens, e.g. other properties of InstanceOfA are initialized 
and some of the functions are used. And then:
...
A.setN(4);
```

I didn't understand from the answer below. Would I need to do

```
A InstanceOfA(4);
```

?

Comment: Have a look at `std::vector`. It has a constructor which takes a size as its argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::vector`

```
class A
{
 public:

 int N; // you should use int for size
 double std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrix; //define the matrix

 //initialize it in the constructor
 A( int size ):N(size), matrix(size*3+3)// or you can use any expression that evaluates an integral value
  {
    //you can initialize the values in matrix here

  }

};
```

**Note**

the expression  `matrix(size*3+3)` initializes the matrix such that, there are `size*3+3` **rows**, the number of columns in each row are not specified yet. You can also specify column sizes in the constructor like

```
for( int i=0;i< N*3+3; ++i) //for each row
{
  matrix[i].resize(N*2);// resize each col to hold N*2 cells,
}
```

**Edit**

As per the modification in question, you can then leave the constructor empty (or initialize any other members), and provide a `setSize` method in class `A`, which will later initialize the size.

```
void setSize(int size){
 N= size;
 matrix.resize( size*3+3);
 for( int i=0;i< N*3+3; ++i) //for each row
 { 
  matrix[i].resize(N*2);// resize each col to hold N*2 cells,
 }
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
A instanceOfA;
//other code
//
instanceOfA.setSize(N);
```

Comment: The inside vector also needs an `std::`

Comment: Also, if N is constant you could still use a vector.

Comment: I have never used a constructor before. **Question:** When I instanciate A in the main() can I say A InstanceOfA;, or does that N has to be given right there as in A InstanceOfA(N);?

Comment: @ABC, as said, if `N` will not determined from outside, then no need to pass *size* parameter in the constructor, you can simply initialize `N` to any value, and use it (or any expression involving it) as the size. Otherwise you have to pass the `size` as parameter when creating an object, like `A ob(100);`.

Comment: Note that the `N` member is redundant, since the vector can tell you its own size.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley The size of the vector is a function of N, not N itself and the function might not be invertible.

Comment: @RakibulHasan I added something to the original question above.

Comment: @RakibulHasan OH!!! Of course!! (<-- per your Edit). I think I need to go to sleep (2:00 am here). The function setting the N builds the array!

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` to capture the matrix. Also, change the type of `N` to `int`.

```
class A
{
  public:

  int N;
  std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrix;
};
```

Define a constructor and initialize the data in the constructor.

```
class A
{
  public:
  A(int n) : N(n)
  {
     int matrixSize = N*N*N+1;
     for (int i = 0; i < matrixSize; ++i )
     {
        matrix.push_back(std::vecotr<double>(matrixSize));
     }
  }

  double N;
  std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrix;
};
```

Comment: I have never used a constructor before. **Question:** When I instanciate A in the main() can I say A InstanceOfA;, or does that N has to be given right there as in A InstanceOfA(N);?

Comment: @ABC, You have to use `A instanceOfA(N);`

Comment: I added details to my question above. I think the need to set N when the object is declared is not convenient for my problem.

Comment: You can hold off on constructing `instanceOfA` until you know the size. It doesn't have to be constructed before that.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to do it with a pointer. If you only allocate your array in constructor and its size will not change during the lifetime of your object, that could be done in this way:

```
class A
{
  public:
  double N;
  double* arr;
  A(double aN):N(aN)
  { arr = new double[3*N+1]; // allocate your array in constructor
    ...                      // do whatever else you need to initialize your object
  } 
  ...
  ~A() { delete[] arr;} // free it in destructor
  ...
}
```

See also the tutorial on [Dynamic Memory](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/).

You will then instantiate your class in one of two ways:

`A a(aN);` 
// this object will be automatically destroyed when it gets out of scope, for example at the end of the function where it was created

`A* a = new A(aN);`

// this object will have to be deleted by yourself when it's no longer needed:

`...
delete a;`

If you don't know N at the moment when you create your object, you can postpone the allocation :

```
class A
{
  public:
  double N;
  double* arr = NULL;
  A() { ... } // do whatever you need in your constructor
  setN(double aN)
  { 
    N = aN;
    arr = new double[3*N+1]; // allocate your array
   } 
  ...
  ~A() { if(arr) delete[] arr;} // free your array in destructor if needed
  ...
}
```

then you can call your object as:

`A a;`

Comment: I have never used a constructor before. **Question:** When I instanciate A in the main() can I say A InstanceOfA;, or does that N has to be given right there as in A InstanceOfA(N);?

Comment: I added details to my question above. I think the need to set N when the object is declared is not convenient for my problem.

Comment: In this case you can postpone allocating your object till you know N. That means, you don't do it in constructor, but in some other function. (see example)